# Running Python multi-threaded process & interrupt a child thread with a signal

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to write a Python multi-threaded script that does the following two things in different threads:

1. Parent: Start Child Thread, Do some simple task, Stop Child Thread
2. Child: Do some long running task.

Below is a simple way to do it. And it works for me:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def child_func():
    while not stop_thread:
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    child_thread = Process(target=child_func)
    stop_thread = False
    child_thread.start()
    time.sleep(3)
    stop_thread = True
    child_thread.join()
```

But a complication arises because in actuality, instead of the while-loop in `child_func()`, I need to run a single long-running process that doesn't stop unless it is killed by Ctrl-C. So I cannot periodically check the value of `stop_thread` in there. So how can I tell my child process to end when I want it to?

I believe the answer has to do with using signals. But I haven't seen a good example of how to use them in this exact situation. Can someone please help by modifying my code above to use signals to communicate between the Child and the Parent thread. And making the child-thread terminate iff the user hits Ctrl-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use the `signal` module here unless you want to do cleanup on your child process. It is possible to stop any child processes using the `terminate` method (which has the same effect as `SIGTERM`)

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def child_func():
    time.sleep(1000)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    event = Event()
    child_thread = Process(target=child_func)
    child_thread.start()
    time.sleep(3)
    child_thread.terminate()
    child_thread.join()
```

The docs are here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate